# Why regarding mean Average Precision for 50 and for 50 to 95? And can you average different evaluations?

Tags: mean, object-detection, yolo, average-precision

I saw a lot of papers using mAP@50 and mAP0:5:95, but in terms of deciding how precise a trained object detection model is, I do not understand why often both values are discussed and shown. Wouldn't it be enough to just discuss around the mAP@50:5:95?

Additionally, I would like to know if you could average e.g. different mAP@50 values from different evaluations to have one "total" mAP@50 for a model. Or would you need to weight the percentages based on the size of the evaluation dataset?

Best regards